# Access a specific item in PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

How can I access value at a certain index of a column in PySpark dataframe for example I want to access value at index 5 of a column named "Category". How can I do that in PySpark syntax?

Comment: do you have an index column added?

Comment: Yes I have. @mayankagrawal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this,

```
value = df.where(df.index == 5).select('Category').collect()[0]['Category']
                                         #assuming 'index' is index column
```

Comment: Thanks @mayank agrawal but what if my data hasn't got any index column?

Comment: Then you have to find some identifier column basis on which you will filter. Pyspark provides a method to add index to your data but you cannot be sure that the 5th index you wanted would be the same as spark allots.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @mayank is good, just continuation if index column is not present.

Data in csv file save it as demo_date.csv:

```
job number,from_date,to_date
1,01-10-2010,31-12-9999
2,02-10-2010,31-12-9999
3,03-10-2010,31-12-9999
```

code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('demo_date.csv', header=True)
#df.show()

val = df.where(col('job number') == lit(2)).select('job number').collect()[0]['job number']

print(val)
```

above worked for me.